# WPF application test automation

Tags: wpf, automated-tests

We have large WPF application and WCF server behind it. I was wandering if there is tool for automated testing of such application similar to selenium for web apps ?

I've googled about the topic, and I've seen some tools, like Ranorex (http://www.ranorex.com/wpf-ui-test-automation.html) and I'd like to hear about the experience that you had with some the tools (it doesn't have to be free).

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Ranorex is that Ranorex Studio is buggy. It crashes relatively often and doesnt seem to have a good support for Team Foundation Server.

For WPF testing I use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It doesnt give you a nice interface for creating the tests like Ranorex. I like to use UI Automation because I generally prefer coded tests.

Ranorex has the advantage that it supports all kinds of applications (windows apps, websites). UI Automation is only for Windows Apps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, I will put UI Automation on my list for evaluation.